# How to get the portlet-hash css class for a Calendar portlet assigned for a custom portlet manager?

Tags: hash, calendar, portlet, plone

I'm trying to fix the month navigation of a calendar portlet assigned for a custom portlet manager. This manager is called from a specific browser page template with:

```html
<div id="calendar"
    tal:content="structure provider:my.custom.portletmanager" />
```

Unfortunately the manager doesn't render a wrapper with the hash for me, so I'm trying to manually append a *kssattr-portlethash* css class to the above `<div>` tag in order to make the month navigation work (*refreshPortlet()* needs it). I tried this:

```py
from plone.portlets.utils import hashPortletInfo
class SectionHomeView(BrowserView):
    """SectionHome browser view
    """
    implements(ISectionHomeView)

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    @property
    def getHash(self):
        info = dict(manager = 'my.custom.portletmanager',
                    category = 'context',
                    key = '/my-section',
                    name = 'mycalendar',
                   )
        return hashPortletInfo(info)
```

Using this code I do get a hash, but calendar navigation still doesn't work. **How can I access the portlet info such as manager, category, key and name in order to compute it right?**

I wish I had the behaviour described by *column.pt* from *plone.app.portlets.browser.templates* and its class *ColumnPortletManagerRenderer* (*portlets/manager.py*) but I don't know how to make my custom manager provide those (ie: like the default managers do).

Comment: Can you provide some code to give us a hint of where to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a PortletManagerRenderer and an EditPortletManagerRenderer installed that know to render hashes, such as:

```
class MyCustomPortletManagerRenderer(ColumnPortletManagerRenderer) :
    """ This custom version of ColumnPortletManagerRenderer points to a new 
    template so that HTML can be customised. 
    """
    adapts(Interface, IThemeSpecific, IBrowserView, IMyCustomPortletManager)
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('column.pt')

    def can_manage_portlets(self):
        context = self._context()
        if not ILocalPortletAssignable.providedBy(context):
            return False
        mtool = getToolByName(context, 'portal_membership')
        return mtool.checkPermission("Portlets: Manage portlets", context)

class MyCustomEditPortletManagerRenderer(ContextualEditPortletManagerRenderer):
    """To allow edit support of the above.
    """
    adapts(Interface, IThemeSpecific, IManageContextualPortletsView, IMyCustomPortletManager)
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('edit-column.pt')
```

Where column.pt looks like:

```
<tal:block repeat="portlet options/portlets">
<div tal:attributes="class string:portletWrapper kssattr-portlethash-${portlet/hash};"
     tal:content="structure python:view.safe_render(portlet['renderer'])" />
</tal:block>
```